# How to group routes by API Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Here is a route rules:

```
Route::apiResources([
    'profile' => ProfileController::class,
    'specialization' => SpecializationController::class,
    'specialization/filter' => SpecializationController::class,
]);
```

I try to add a custom route into apiResource above:

```
'register/code/verify' => [RegisterVerifyController::class, 'verify']
```

As result I got this:

```
Route::apiResources([
    'profile' => ProfileController::class,
    'specialization' => SpecializationController::class,
    'specialization/filter' => SpecializationController::class,
     'register/code/verify' => [RegisterVerifyController::class, 'verify']
]);
```

It does not work. How to do that to be able call route with `api/` prefix like `apiResources`?

Comment: These your route codes, what file did you write them in? ```web.php```?

Comment: All I posted is inside api.php routing

Comment: Then just define your routes one by one

Comment: The ```api``` prefix is assigned automatically. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define routes inside the `routes/api.php` file, all routes are automatically prefixed with `api/`. The likely cause of your issue is the following route definition:

```
'register/code/verify' => [RegisterVerifyController::class, 'verify']
```

You're not able to specify particular actions for a route when using the [`apiResource` or `apiResources`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_apiResources) route facades. Each array element you pass to `apiResouces` should be a `kvp` (key-value pair) where the `key` is a `string` specifying the `route` and the `value` is also a `string` specifying the `Controller` that `route` maps to ([see api docs](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_apiResources)). What you've done with the above is provide the `value` as an `array`, which results in an `ErrorException` due to an `Array to string conversion`.

What you can do is the folllowing:

```
Route::apiResources([
    'profile' => ProfileController::class,
    'specialization' => SpecializationController::class,
    'specialization/filter' => SpecializationController::class,
]);

Route::match(
    ['GET', 'POST'],
    'register/code/verify', 
    [RegisterVerifyController::class, 'verify']
);
```

I don't know the HTTP verbs you want to use with the `verify` route, so I have used `match` with both `GET` and `POST` but you can replace that with whatever works for you.

If you have other actions inside your `RegisterVerifyController` other than `verify` and still want to use it as an `apiResource`, you can add it back in to your group, just don't specify any actions:

```
Route::apiResources([
    'profile' => ProfileController::class,
    'specialization' => SpecializationController::class,
    'specialization/filter' => SpecializationController::class,
    'register/verify' => RegisterVerifyController::class,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you define your route codes in `.../routes/api.php` file, the `api/` prefix is assigned to your routes by default. But from your code above it seems you are defining your routes in the `routes/web.php` file(just a guess).
A way to add the prefix to your route would be this way:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
Route::apiResources([
    'profile' => ProfileController::class,
    'specialization' => SpecializationController::class,
    'specialization/filter' => SpecializationController::class,
     'register/code/verify' => [RegisterVerifyController::class, 'verify']
]);
});
```

UPDATE:
Define your routes this way

```
Route::get('profile', [ProfileController::class]);
Route::get('specialization', [SpecializationController::class]);
Route::get('specialization/filter', [SpecializationController::class]);
Route::get('register/code/verify', [RegisterVerifyController::class, 'verify');
```

The `api/` prefix is added automatically